# Appending in list of list

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I have applied `Kmeans` on a dataset `top_feat` represent the features and I have created list of lists in cluster.

I want to get which feature belongs to which cluster. But using this code, I get same values in all the clusters. Ideally I should get values as

```py
         len(cluster[0])=249 #(I don't know the exact number)
         len(cluster[1])=1
         len(cluster[2])=1
         #..
         len(cluster[5])=1.
```

I have 2500 features in total. But running this code, I get length of all clusters as 2500. It is as if all clusters are getting all the features.

I have used a for loop from 0 to 2500; such that `cluster[w[i]] = top_feat[i]` where `w[i]` is the value of the label. `w= kmeans.labels_`

So, `if w[i] == 1`, it will be cluster[1].append(top_feat[i]). Here, `max(w) = 6`

```py
        cluster = [[]]*((max(w)+1))
        for i in range(0,2500):
            cluster[w[i]].append(top_feat[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sublists in `[[]]*((max(w)+1))` all refer to the same list, so changing one will change them all, instead of multiplying, create `max(w) + 1` distinct lists with a list comprehension:

```
cluster = [[] for _ in range(max(w) + 1)]
```